# How to prefer `defaults` numpy over `conda-forge` numpy when installing `conda-forge` package

Tags: numpy, package, conda

I prefer using the MKL toolchain from the usual `defaults` channel provided by Continuum.  Like many people, though, I find myself installing quite a few packages from the [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/#about) channel.

Consider, for example, the [python-graphviz](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-graphviz) package.  The install command is

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz
```

which results in some undesired changes to dependencies

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

cvxopt:          1.1.7-py27_0          --> 1.1.9-py27_blas_openblas_201  conda-forge [blas_openblas]
gsl:             2.2.1-h8267d9d_2      --> 2.2.1-blas_openblas_2         conda-forge [blas_openblas]
numpy:           1.13.3-py27hbcc08e0_0 --> 1.13.3-py27_blas_openblas_200 conda-forge [blas_openblas]
scikit-learn:    0.19.1-py27h445a80a_0 --> 0.19.1-py27_blas_openblas_200 conda-forge [blas_openblas]
scipy:           0.19.1-py27h1edc525_3 --> 0.19.1-py27_blas_openblas_202 conda-forge [blas_openblas]
```

I don't want to change to the OpenBlas `numpy`, so I manually handle all the dependencies and then

```
conda install -c conda-forge --no-deps python-graphviz
```

which works fine but is laborious and invites mistakes.

I had thought that if I added `conda-forge` as a low priority channel with

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
```

then it would stop trying to override the `numpy` installation, but this turned out to be untrue.  The output of `conda config --show` now contains, as expected,

```
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org
channel_priority: True
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
```

but if I try installing something (without the command-line switch) with, say, `conda install pycwt`, then I still get

```
Package plan for installation in environment /conda:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  pycwt:        0.3.0a22-py_0         conda-forge
  tqdm:         4.19.4-py27hdfef72e_0            

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  cvxopt:       1.1.7-py27_0                      --> 1.1.9-py27_blas_openblas_201  conda-forge [blas_openblas]
  gsl:          2.2.1-h8267d9d_2                  --> 2.2.1-blas_openblas_2         conda-forge [blas_openblas]
  numpy:        1.13.3-py27hbcc08e0_0             --> 1.13.3-py27_blas_openblas_200 conda-forge [blas_openblas]
  scikit-learn: 0.19.1-py27h445a80a_0             --> 0.19.1-py27_blas_openblas_200 conda-forge [blas_openblas]
  scipy:        0.19.1-py27h1edc525_3             --> 0.19.1-py27_blas_openblas_202 conda-forge [blas_openblas]
```

Is there a way to prefer `defaults` over `conda-forge` updates when I install `conda-forge` packages?

**Edit:** Added more information about `conda config` output and non-switch behavior

Comment: conda-forge now provides an MKL built version of numpy. Your question specifically asks to keep the defaults version of numpy for MKL... but an alternative solution is to use the conda-forge version of numpy built with MKL. See https://github.com/conda-forge/numpy-feedstock/issues/153#issuecomment-478619215

Answer (score 9):

You might want to use `pinned_packages` feature of conda config.

Either manually edit your `.condarc` file (it's location can be seen in the output of `conda config --show-sources`) by changing/adding these lines:

```
pinned_packages:
  - defaults::numpy
```

Or from command line:

```
conda config --add pinned_packages defaults::numpy
```

This will ensure that `numpy` will be only installed / updated from defaults channel and not from conda-forge.

Answer (score 2):

A literal translation of the expression

> *prefer **defaults** over **conda-forge** while installing the `python-graphviz` package from **conda-forge***

would be

```bash
conda install -c defaults -c conda-forge conda-forge::python-graphviz
```

This works because `conda` accepts multiple `-c` arguments, given priority according to order (first is highest, last is lowest).<sup>**1**</sup> The `conda-forge::` overrides the priority and only looks for `python-graphviz` on the **conda-forge** channel.

It may also be sufficient to simply do:

```bash
conda install conda-forge::python-graphviz
```

which should respect the user's configured channels, except for using **conda-forge** for the specified package.

---

<sub>**[1]** You may need to have `conda config --set channel_priority strict` for this to behave.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Adding the channel to the install command makes that channel the highest priority channel. If you add the `conda-forge` channel to the end of your configuration **and do not specify it in the install command** you will get dependencies from the first channel that matches them.

Comment: This is incorrect.  After using `conda config --append channels conda-forge` the install still tries to use the `conda-forge` packages, despite the `--append` flag having added it to the end of the configuration.  I quite agree that one might *expect* that behavior but unfortunately it does not work that way.

Comment: My experience is that this answer is correct. Can you edit the output of `conda config --show` into the question? The reason I'm asking is because I'm wondering if you have conda forge higher up the list as well.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I have so updated the question.  As you will now be able to see `conda-forge` is at the bottom.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with your system then... this is my output of conda config and installing the second package you mentioned: https://gist.github.com/bryanwweber/0d4c38dbae137dacb2edf9b179c94c19 as you can see, it doesn't try to replace numpy or any other package. AFAIK, the behavior that I'm experiencing and that I described in my answer is the expected behavior of conda and its the behavior that I've noticed since I started using conda a few years ago...

Comment: What is your version of conda?

Comment: According to `conda --version` I am running version 4.3.30.  I ran a `diff` of my `config` against the one posted by *darthbith* and found some slight differences in the ordering of *custom channels*.  But no *custom channels* involve `conda-forge`.

Comment: I'm sorry then, I really have no idea what's going on. How did you install Anaconda? What OS?

Comment: @BrianB For what its worth, I just ran into this problem on a brand new installation of Anaconda on a Windows system, although I wasn't able to reproduce it on Linux or macOS. My solution was to specify the channel in the install command, let it do the downgrade, then run `conda update --all`, which is a silly hack, but effective. Sorry I couldn't be more help before!

Comment: @darthbirth Would you mind editing your answer to incorporate that vital platform-specific finding? This answer would then be authoritative in all edge cases. (*Windows. Always Windows.*)

Comment: @Cecil Curry My problems have been on linux (CentOS7), so although darthbirth has reproduced it on Windows, it is not fair to assume the problem lies there.